# Add path from remote ssh server

Tags: linux, ssh, path

I have a remote SSH server that holds the exe file (at /usr/bin/linux). I want to run the exe files from the server on images on my local hosts, i.e. add me@remote:usr/bin/linux to my local path. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system has it installed, you can use `sshfs` to make the programs appear to be local:

```
mkdir ${HOME}/linux-progs
sshfs me@remote:/usr/bin/linux ${HOME}/linux-progs
PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/linux-progs
run-something-from-linux-progs
```

When you're done with the remote filesystem, you run `fusermount -u ${HOME}/linux-progs` to unmount the remote file system.

Answer (score 0):

Running them locally would mean you'd have to copy them over one way or another (on the fly, once, periodically etc.). Another option would be to pipe the input and output back and forth, then the files would be executed remotely. Which option is more suitable depends on the size of your input etc. If you just want to open a remote session with X (or something along those lines) a simple script in your /urs/bin/ and some ssh keys are probably the way to go.